# A question on zygmund class estimates

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

If $f \in \mathbf{L}_{2}^{2}(\mathbf{R}^2)$, show that $f$ satisfies the Zygmund class estimate:

$|f(x+2y)-2f(x+y)+f(x)|\leq c|y|$.

I know that $f\in \mathbf{L}_{2}^{2}(\mathbf{R}^2)$ satisfies the Lipschitz class, but
how do you show it for the zygmund class?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you mean $c|y|^2$ instead of $c|y|$?

Comment: @robjohn the question says $c|y|$, so it should be that.

Comment: If the function is Lipschitz of constant $L$, then isn't it true that by triangle inequality the function is going to be Ziegmund with constant $2L$?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg if you don't mind, could you please explain?